# Scrapy only scraping the first two pages

Tags: javascript, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape a website but need to use splash in all pages because their content created dynamically. Right now it renders only the first 2 pages, even though there are 47 pages in total.

Here's the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ['https://jobs.citizensbank.com/search-jobs']

    def start_requests(self):
        filters_script = """function main(splash)
                                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                                splash:wait(3)
                                return splash:html()
                            end"""

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={'lua_source': filters_script})

    def parse(self, response):
        cars_urls = response.xpath('.//section[@id="search-results-list"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for car_url in cars_urls:
            absolute_car_url = response.urljoin(car_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_car_url,
                          callback=self.parse_car)

        script_at_page_1 = """function main(splash)
                                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                                splash:wait(3)

                                next_button = splash:select("a[class=next]")
                                next_button.mouse_click()
                                splash:wait(3)
                                return {
                                    url = splash:url(),
                                    html = splash:html()
                                }
                            end"""

        script_at_page_2 = """function main(splash)
                                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                                splash:wait(3)

                                next_button = splash:select("a[class=next]")
                                next_button.mouse_click()
                                splash:wait(3)
                                return {
                                    url = splash:url(),
                                    html = splash:html()
                                }
                            end"""

        script = None
        if response.url is not self.start_urls[0]:
            script = script_at_page_2
        else:
            script = script_at_page_1

        yield SplashRequest(url=response.url,
                            callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute',
                            args={'lua_source': script})


    def parse_car(self, response):
        jobtitle = response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="title"]/text()').extract_first()
        location = response.xpath('//span[@class="job-info"]/text()').extract_first()
        jobid = response.xpath('//span[@class="job-id job-info"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield {'jobtitle': jobtitle,
                'location': location,
                'jobid': jobid}
```

I've played with it in every way I could think off but it didn't work.
I'm new to scrapy so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to use Splash for this. If you look at the network tab of your browser inspector you will see it is making requests to this URL under XHR:

https://jobs.citizensbank.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage=3&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&Latitude=&Longitude=&ShowRadius=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=0&SearchType=5&CategoryFacetTerm=&CategoryFacetType=&LocationFacetTerm=&LocationFacetType=&KeywordType=&LocationType=&LocationPath=&OrganizationIds=&PostalCode=&fc=&fl=&fcf=&afc=&afl=&afcf=

Try making requests to this URL and change the page each time. If you have trouble you may need to look at the headers of the XHR request and replicate them as well. If you click the link the JSON will load in your browser. So just set page 1 as your start_url and over ride start_requests as follows:

```
start_urls = ['https://jobs.citizensbank.com/search-jobs/results?ActiveFacetID=0&CurrentPage={}&RecordsPerPage=15&Distance=50&RadiusUnitType=0&Keywords=&Location=&Latitude=&Longitude=&ShowRadius=False&CustomFacetName=&FacetTerm=&FacetType=0&SearchResultsModuleName=Search+Results&SearchFiltersModuleName=Search+Filters&SortCriteria=0&SortDirection=0&SearchType=5&CategoryFacetTerm=&CategoryFacetType=&LocationFacetTerm=&LocationFacetType=&KeywordType=&LocationType=&LocationPath=&OrganizationIds=&PostalCode=&fc=&fl=&fcf=&afc=&afl=&afcf=']

def start_requests(self):
    num_pages = 10
    for page in range(1, num_pages):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0].format(page), callback=self.parse)
```

It's also worth noting you can set the RecordsPerPage setting. You may be able to set it higher and possibly get all records on one page or make less requests to get all records.